# Can you perform aggregations or joins with falcor?

Tags: falcor

Often a client needs aggregations or joins over the data. How would you handle that in falcor? I don't see any notion of transform or join in the docs. Perhaps with `call`? It is introduced as a way of executing side effects, but perhaps could also perform transforms or joins.

However, it seems you'd then have to embed functions throughout your graph for every aggregation you might need.

Update:

For example, return the mean of a property, like

`select avg(x) from foo`

or the mean, grouped by another property

`select g, avg(x) from foo group-by g`

Answer (score 2):

What kind of aggregations and joins do you mean? They are mostly solved by references.

For example, this SQL:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID, Orders.SomeOrderStuff
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID;
```

Translates roughly to:

```
model.get(
    ['customers', {from: 0, to: 100}, 'orders', {from: 0, to: 100}, ['id', 'someOrderStuff']
).then(function(response) {
    // do stuff
});
```

in the model (client-side). Server-side, you need to implement routes that return `$ref`s.

(Tell me if you need a more detailed explanation.)